# Como mover vários arquivos ZIP de uma vez com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

eu estou criando uma função para gerenciar arquivos usando python.
eu gostaria que essa função fizesse o seguinte: pegasse todos os meus arquivos zip ou mp3 (ou com outros formatos) e movesse todos de uma vez para uma pasta.

```
   os.chdir('C:\\')
   shutil.copy('C:\\Users\\ODIN\\Downloads\\*.*', 'C:\\ODIN\\d')
```

Comment: Tem como descrever pelo menos uma das suas tentativas? Se pressionar [edit], você pode alterar a sua pergunta para poder adicionar o código.

Comment: Já deu uma pesquisada no google alguém já deve ter passado por esse problema ou por algo semelhante!

Comment: OBRIGADO VOU VERIFICAR

Answer (score 2):

Acho que você está procurando por [`shutil.move()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move):

`shutil.move("pasta/atual/seu.doc", "nova/pasta/seu.doc")`

Não apenas para arquivos, mas também para diretórios.

Recomendo uma lida na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move).

Comment: OK OBRIGADO VOU USAR  E VERIFICAR A DOCUMENTACAO

Answer (score 2):

Creio que esta solução atende a tua necessidade.

```
__author__ = '@britodfbr'

import shutil
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, basename


def move(path_origem, path_destino, ext='zip'):
    for item in [join(path_origem, f) for f in listdir(path_origem) if isfile(join(path_origem, f)) and f.endswith(ext)]:
        #print(item)
        shutil.move(item, join(path_destino, basename(item)))
        print('moved "{}" -> "{}"'.format(item, join(path_destino, basename(item))))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    move('/tmp/a', '/tmp/b')
```

Saída:

```
moved "/tmp/a/file7.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file7.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file4.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file4.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file0.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file0.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file3.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file3.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file1.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file1.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file6.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file6.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file9.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file9.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file2.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file2.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file5.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file5.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file10.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file10.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file8.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file8.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file01.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file01.zip"
```

Comment: OK OBRIGADO VAI SER MUITO UTIL